# memory leak - application exited with signal 9

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-leaks, memory-management

I have an application which is dealing with many data structures, uiimageviews, videos, creating bit map context and so on. Every time the application is crashing on its continuous usage for a long time. The application is crashing with the memory warning --> Application exited abnormally with signal 9. What may be its reason. What does signal 9 means.

Comment: I have the same problem, but it's occurring only after I sent an update to the AppStore..?!? if I install the same app with an ad hoc certificate it works fine. Anyone knows why?

Comment: There is some discussion currently going on about the App Store delivering corrupting binaries. Unfortunately my app experienced the same issue. Thanks Apple.

Comment: I was getting **Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9** whenever I started recording from instruments. It basically killed any runs directly done from Xcode.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is due to the memory issue. Your app is using lot of memory due that is app is killed..

Comment: It is due to memory issue. but signal 9 means what type of memory issue. It may be due to data structures, uiimageview or what it is.

Comment: Signal number 9 is [SIGKILL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL). It means your application is being terminated immediately, without any chance to clean up or catch and handle the signal.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this posting

http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Mar/msg00837.html

It sounds like it might be related.

Answer (score 3):

It can also be a privacy/permission issue.
We forgot to add NSCameraUsageDescription and UILaunchStoryboardName to Info.plist file and our app crashed with error  `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9`

After adding the following lines to Info.plist the app sopped crashing.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>The app would like to let you make a picture.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>The app would like to let you choose an item from your Photos.</string>
```

[image: Terminated due to signal 9.]