# App downloaded from App Store fails to start, no crash or crash log

Tags: iphone, crash, app-store

My App fails to start when downloaded from the App Store, see below. No crash or crash log. Any ideas?

```
Jul  5 08:54:40 unknown fairplayd.N90[41] <Error>: libMobileGestalt computeUniqueDeviceID: total time for bb to return imei: 0
Jul  5 08:54:40 unknown SpringBoard[52] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 1310: (os/kern) failure
Jul  5 08:54:40 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:xxxxxxxx.Xxxxxxx[0x5760]) Exited: Killed: 9
Jul  5 08:54:40 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:xxxxxxxx.Xxxxxxx[0x5760]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483647 seconds
Jul  5 08:54:40 unknown SpringBoard[52] <Warning>: Application 'Xxxxxxx' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Jul  5 08:54:40 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleFairplayTextCrypterSession::fairplayOpen() failed, error -42110
> 
Jul  5 08:55:29 unknown lockdownd[26] <Notice>: 00381000 spawn_and_handle_checkin: Timeout waiting for com.apple.crashreportmover service agent to checkin. spawn=1341471314 select=1341471314 now=1341471329
Jul  5 08:55:29 unknown ReportCrash[1346] <Error>: libMobileGestalt computeUniqueDeviceID: total time for bb to return imei: 0
Jul  5 08:55:29 unknown ReportCrash[1346] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/stacks-2012-07-05-085529.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Jul  5 08:55:30 unknown lockdownd[26] <Notice>: 00381000 spawn_service_agent: Could not look up service in the map
Jul  5 08:55:30 unknown lockdownd[26] <Notice>: 00381000 spawn_and_handle_checkin: Could not spawn the com.apple.crashreportcopy service agent:InvalidService 
> 
Jul  5 08:55:30 unknown lockdownd[26] <Notice>: 00381000 spawn_service_agent: Could not look up service in the map
Jul  5 08:55:30 unknown lockdownd[26] <Notice>: 00381000 spawn_and_handle_checkin: Could not spawn the com.apple.crashreportcopy service agent:InvalidService
```

Comment: It seems to be [a memory issue][1]. 

Take a look at [this][2] SO question also.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959038/memory-leak-application-exited-with-signal-9
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980636/ios-low-memory-crash-but-very-low-memory-usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's been some problems with Apps downloaded from the AppStore over the last couple of nights being corrupted from the AppStore. Delete and re-install from the AppStore.

http://www.marco.org/2012/07/04/app-store-corrupt-binaries