# What is Killed:9 and how to fix in macOS Terminal?

Tags: python, macos, machine-learning, terminal

I have a simple Python code for a machine learning project. I have a relatively big database of spontaneous speech. I started to train my speech model. Since it's a huge database I let it work overnight. In the morning I woke up and saw a mysterious

**Killed: 9**

line in my Terminal. Nothing else. There is no other error message or something to work with. The code run well for about 6 hours which is 75% of the whole process so I really don't understand whats went wrong.

What is Killed:9 and how to fix it? It's very frustrating to lose hours of computing time...

I'm on macOS Mojave beta if it's matter. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Signal 9 is UNIX/POSIX signal `SIGKILL`. Check if any other processes on your system could have raised it. On Mac OS, some events (e.g. local notification) can, anecdotally, cause this signal to be raised if the underlying event is not handled.

Comment: Thanks Andrey! Sorry for the noob question but how can I check this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not well-versed enough with Mac OS to be able to give strong guidance. There's some further discussion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338884/what-does-exited-abnormally-with-signal-9-killed-9-mean) and you might be able to use a tool such as strace to see what happens in the last moments of the process (at a cost to performance as the process runs).

Comment: I am having very similar issue, also on OSX Mojave. Have you resolved it?

Comment: @Danijel Unfortunately I couldn't resolve it. I tried to cool my machine more if it's a thermal throttling problem but it didn't help. I suggest - if it's possible in your case - to split your task into smaller subtasks.

Comment: I resolved my problem. It was internal to the program I was running: it had some kind of a memory leak, so the memory usage would build up to giga bytes, eventualy crashing. Run your task and look into Activity Monitor app to check memory state while running it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Killed: 9" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978241/what-does-killed-9-error-mean)

Comment: I have noticed the same error while upgrading terraform to higher version by simply copying the executable to /bin location. But I was able to resolve it by first deleting the existing terraform executable and then copying the new one.

Answer (score 3):

This fixed it for me; no idea how/why it works:

```bash
codesign --sign - --force --preserve-metadata=entitlements,requirements,flags,runtime <path-to-binary>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I updated my Mac OS version from Catalina to Big Sur. I was trying to run a binary and facing the `Killed: 9` issue.

I was able to resolve this issue by following the steps below (I referred to [this Apple StackExchange post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258623/how-to-fix-killed-9-error-in-mac-os) for these steps) :-

1. Download [UPX](https://upx.github.io/) via Homebrew - `brew install upx`
2. Then decompress the binary - `upx -d /path/to/binary/file`

Answer (score 0):

i've got the same issue when i install mongodb
that bebasue it use 'cp' something to your bin path

so enter your bin path

```
cd /usr/local/bin
open .
```

then delete the new file

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the node version.
In my case, that helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).