# unable to install firebase tools cli on macOS

Tags: firebase, macos, firebase-cli

I've tried to install firebase tools on my macOS several times .
I used npm , the auto install script and standalone binary, but nothing have worked .

When I write on my terminal commands like `firebase login` it shows me

> "killed : 9"

None of the firebase commands work . Even if I tried commands like `firebase help` or `firebase -v` , the terminal always show me the same "killed : 9" message .

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This error is typically caused by another process that has a memory leak, check the usage of your device and look for any apps that have extremely high usages and end the process. This should allow you to run a fresh command window for CLI commands.

Similar:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258623/how-to-fix-killed-9-error-in-mac-os
- [What is Killed:9 and how to fix in macOS Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833310/what-is-killed9-and-how-to-fix-in-macos-terminal)

Comment: thanks for the answer ! i tried that with many other things .. it now shows me **Pkg: Error reading from file.**

Comment: sounds like it could be a corrupted install - `npm ci -g` may work