# Cannot pip3 install anything. Error Killed: 9

Tags: python, macos, pip

Whenever I try to install anything through the visual studio code terminal, I am unable to. I am using  MacOS. I keep getting the error message `Killed: 9` whenever I try to install anything.

```
pip3 install pyautogui 
Killed: 9
```

Comment: Have you tried closing and restarting visual studio? That might be enough to reset whatever has gone wrong.

Comment: yes I have, still doesn't work.

Comment: Didn't you find any clue by searching your error message over the internet ?

Answer (score 0):

I looked it up and found a couple things that might fix your problem:

1. Close the terminal window and open a new one.
2. Try the same command, but use sudo.
3. Try this command: `brew reinstall pcre2 gettext`
4. Download UPX using `brew install UPX`, then decompress the binary with `upx -d /path/to/App.app/MacOS/App` (This one seemed to help multiple people with the same problem.)
5. There might be another process causing the error. Kill that process, close the terminal and start a new one, and try again.

Links:

[How to fix "Killed: 9" error in mac os?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258623/how-to-fix-killed-9-error-in-mac-os)

[What is Killed:9 and how to fix in macOS Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833310/what-is-killed9-and-how-to-fix-in-macos-terminal)