# Pip and flask run are both giving me a killed 9 message

Tags: python, flask, pip

I am trying to run a flask app on my computer. It is my own app and I was playing with it a month ago and everything was working fine.

Now, when I try the flask run in the venv, I get a killed 9. I also can't execute pip, also getting a killed 9.

I cloned my project from github, thinking something might have have gone wrong in the env. I run `(main)$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt`. It says `clli` can't be downloaded, and after that, `pip3` gets the "*killed 9*" message.

I tried the other solution running this - `brew reinstall pcre2 gettext` - didn't work.

Any suggestions?

I was expecting the app to start running and I could see what the site looked like and do some editing and whatnot.

UPDATE: Ok, I was able to fix some of the problem. I installed cffi before the rest of the requirements, so I can use pip and python. Flask run is still giving me the killed 9 message.

Comment: It appears you're on `macOS`. Your `Killed: 9` might be related to a bug where `macOS` sees `cp` or a binary integrity issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to revert back to Python 3.9. Version 3.10 doesn't support Mapping from request.

Answer (score 0):

(Based on the limited info) It appears you're on `macOS`. Your [`Killed: 9` might be related to a bug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258623/how-to-fix-killed-9-error-in-mac-os) where `macOS` sees `cp` or a binary integrity issue.

[Script]
Check your scripts. Walkaround: use `rm` before `cp`

[Settings]
Check binary integrity settings

[Terminal]
Close and reopen terminal.

[**Edit**]
See this [SO for a UPX 'hack'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71730715/20107918)

Comment: I HAVE FIXED IT!!!! I had to revert my python back to 3.9, 3.10 doesn't support Mapping from requests

Comment: Great . Kindly update your question accordingly. That'll be of assistance to others. Just for noting. [Flask has some challenges with Python 3.10](https://github.com/prakhar1989/docker-curriculum/issues/325). Regarding `mapping` generally, [depreciated `mapping` from 3.4 was dropped in 3.10](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/5478)